# What is a provisioning profile used for when developing iPhone applications?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

What is the purpose of a provisioning profile and why is it needed when developing an iPhone application?  If I don't have a provisioning profile, what happens?

Comment: It is used when you are going to distribute your application on iTune.

Comment: @Siddiqui, not only for that. You can't even test you app on real device without provisioning profile, let alone distribution.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

A Quote from : [iPhone Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/information/Apple_Developer_Program_Information_8_12_15.pdf) (~8MB PDF)

> A provisioning profile is a collection of digital entities that uniquely ties developers and devices to an authorized iPhone Development Team and enables a device to be used for testing. A Development Provisioning Profile must be installed on each device on which you wish to run your application code. Each Development Provisioning Profile will contain a set of iPhone Development Certificates, Unique Device Identifiers and an App ID.
>   Devices specified within the provisioning profile can be used for testing only by those individuals whose iPhone Development Certificates are included in the profile. A single device can contain multiple provisioning profiles.

Comment: So how come you need a matching provisional profile when you do a app store distribution?   The app store distribution profile does not contain any devices, but it is necessary when signing for app store.

Comment: @mskw: It will verify that your developer account created the app.

Comment: It also defines the allowed entitlements like push notification support, icloud and keychain masks, etc.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013839-CH33-SW1
updated Link

Comment: I came across this [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21421401) to fix the link. I cannot judge if the link is correct - but since the link is broken, it would be great if someone with the appropriate knowledge could fix it!

Comment: The current link does not contain the quote as given in this answer. @Akusete: could you please update the link?

Comment: For example, if i log with user xyz and i create my profiles with user zyx, can be problem? I'm having a problem like above and i get this error: Error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for PerformaMobile.iOS on iOS. (PerformaMobile.iOS)

Answer (score 14):

You need it to install development iPhone applications on development devices.

Here's how to create one, and the reference for this answer:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone

Another link:
  http://iphone.timefold.com/provisioning.html

Answer (score 5):

**Development Provisioning Profile**

Apple cares about security and as you know it is not possible to install **any** application on a real iOS device. Apple has several legal ways to do it:

- When you need to **test/debug** an app on a real device the `Development Provisioning Profile` allows you to do it
- When you **publish** an app you send a `Distribution Provisioning Profile`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60829450/4770877) and Apple after review reassign it by they own key

`Development Provisioning Profile` is stored on device and contains:

- Application ID - application which are going to run
- List of Development certificates - who can debug the app
- List of devices - which devices can run this app

`Xcode` by default take cares about it

Comment: I DON'T have any provisioning profile, but I CAN install my app on my iPhone via cable & TestFlight :/