# What is CA certificate, and why do we need it?

Tags: ssl, x509, pki

I've just read [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20161213142308/https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html) about what is HTTPS service, and understand the basic of https.

When requesting https content, the server will send a public key to browser, so that every time, the browser receive data will decrypted with the public key.

My question is what is CA certificate for? Why do we need it?

Comment: You don't. Check out [Let's Encrypt.](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: @erickson Why there is an Authority? My understanding is that, https is point to point, strictly between 2 parties.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @erickson Lets Encrypt still has a CA - the “difference” about LE is that a) it’s free, and b) it’s automatically renewed (or if you can’t automatically it’s probably not worth bothering) - so a double win!

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu SSL certificate come with a public key, then you can use it in HTTPS connection. However, it is not recommended to trust SSL certificates that are not signed by recognised CAs.

It is because reputable web-sites are most likely asking recognised CAs to sign their certificates. Average crackers do not do that.

Comment: @jww You said: "This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development." Disagree. IMO it is quite on-topic and very much programming/development related. Every IT/deops/etc problem starts with development of software (and/or hardware) solution - using some computation algorithms and protocols. Information privacy and security is especially science-dense programming specialization with potentially high stakes.

Answer (score 44):

A CA certificate is a digital certificate issued by a certificate authority (CA), so SSL clients (such as web browsers) can use it to verify the SSL certificates sign by this CA.

For example, stackoverflow.com uses *Let's Encrypt* to sign its servers, and SSL certificates sent by stackoverflow.com mention they are signed by *Let's Encrypt*.
Your browser contains the CA certificate from *Let's Encrypt* and so the browser can use that CA certificate to verify the stackoverflow's SSL certificate and make sure you are indeed talking to real server, not man-in-the-middle.

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20833/233126 provides a more detail explanation about how TLS/SSL certificates work.

Answer (score 15):

**Signature, Certificate**

[[Encoding Encryption Hashing]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75401377/4770877)

[[ASN.1, DER, PEM]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592073/4770877)

**Digital Signature**

`Digital signature` - ensures that some data(like message, document, file...) is sent by the intended side - verify Integrity, authenticity, Non-repudiation. Digital signatures can be **attached**(data is a part of signature) or **detached**[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592073/4770877)(data is not a part of signature and they are transported separately) to message.

```
//Create a signature by owner
1. owner of asymmetric key pair(private/public keys)
2. calculate a check sum of data: Message(M) -> Hash message by some hash algorithm -> message digest(MD1)
3. encode(**sign**) calculated check sum: encrypt message digest(MD1) by private key -> Digital signature(DS)

//Check a signature
1. calculate a check sum of data: Message(M) -> Hash message by some hash algorithm -> message digest(MD2)
2. decode(**verify**) digital signature: decrypt Digital signature(DS) by owner's public key -> message digest(MD1)
3. compare check sums from step 1 and 2: is MD2 == MD1
```

**Digital Certificate**

`Certificate` - is a file which contains owner's **public key** and other owner's info. This file is signed by Certificate Authority(CA) with `digital signature` - the entire certificate is converted to .der and hash sum is calculated

```
Subject - owner' data(from CSR)
Issuer - CA who issued a certificate
Serial Number - CA's unique identifier
Valid From/To 

Public Key
Signature Algorithm
Signature Value

version
extension

//fingerprint - it is not a part of certificate, which is calculated by demand and can be used as unique identifier. It is a hash of the entire certificate in DER(.der) format
...
```

**certificate authority(CA) certificate** guarantees that you are who you are.

- Public certificate authority(CA)
- Private certificate authority(CA)

**Self-signed certificate** is a certificate which is not issued by certificate authority(CA) and where subject name is equals issuer name. Please note that Root certificate is self signed.

You are able to create Self-signed certificate on Mac:

```
Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Create a Certificate
```

mySelfSignedCertificate.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

[image]

**Verified** certificate is a certificate which is a part of trusted certificate chains, where root certificate already was added in your keychain(trusted store)(by System, browser, you...)

**Chain of trust** (Certificate chain) - is a hierarchy of certificates to validate an issuer. Every certificate in this hierarchy is signed and issued by patent certificate

```
Root(trust anchor) Certificate - [Intermediate(subordinate, issuing) Certificate] - End-user(end-entity, leaf, subscriber) Certificate
```

- **Root certificate** - signs and issues only Intermediate certificates.
- **Intermediate certificate** - signs and issues other Intermediate certificate and End-user Certificate.
- **End-user certificate** - **cannot** sign and issue certificates.

[[OpenSSL verify certificate chain]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75593242/4770877)

Mac Keychain propose you next certificate validation options:

```
//System trust
This certificate is valid

//Manually added self-signed certificate and manually trusted
This certificate is masked as trusted for this account

//Manually added self-signed certificate
This certificate has not been verified by a third party
```

Validation/verification algorithm - Since child certificate is signed by parent(using parent's private key) and root certificate is self signed, and every child certificate has a link to it's parent(child's Issuer name equals to parent's Subject name) and root's certificate Issuer name equals to root's certificate Subject name. It means that the simplest way(without extensions and it's constraints) is just **name matching**. Don't forger that root certificate is usually pre-downloaded and intermediate and user-ended are usually downloaded during handshake

[Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/) uses self-signed certificate to sniff a traffic  using Man-in-the-middle(MITM) proxy - **Https ProxyServer**

```
client - with added Charles Certificate and encrypt messages by Charles public key
Https ProxyServer - has Server's Certificate and proxy message and encrypt it by Server public key
Server
```

**SSL Pinning** is a mechanism when a client during handshake check/validate a retrieved certificate and compare it with local copy and fail the connection if it is not verified

[[Certificate Signing Request(CSR)]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303097/4770877) - Info with a public key and other data which is send to `CA`

[image]

Comment: The parts of this diagram about asymmetric encryption are irrelevant, or wrong if they refer to TLS.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, could you please provide some resources where I can draw about it ?

Answer (score 12):

Most certificates do not cost $800 and CAs such as  Let's Encrypt are free (at the cost of added inconvenience of periodic and often renewals)

The issue is why would the client trust that the server is the correct server? The answer is that an authority, a CA, issues and vouches for the server certificate. In some manner the CA, verifies the certificate requester. Then the CA provides a public interface to verify a certificate's authenticity. The CA must be know to the client that that is achieved by the OS and/or in the case the browser may also have embedded CAs.