# Is iOS provisioning profile similar to Android Manifest File

Tags: android, ios, profile, provisioning

I am experienced Android Dev trying to understand iOS eco-system. I have been researching the "provisioning profile" and don't really understand what it is used for.  I have read the following SO post and it makes me think that provisioning profile is basically the manifest file? Or is it similar to the signing keystore?

My assumption is because the android manifest tells the device how my app will behave, what services or permissions it needs, whether it is exportable by other apps, ect... It seems the provisioning profile might have a similar role?

Reference to question here: 
[What is a provisioning profile used for when developing iPhone applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362652/what-is-a-provisioning-profile-used-for-when-developing-iphone-applications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Provisioning Profile is part of iOS security.  When the user launches an app, ios verifies the provisioning profile embedded in that app to determine if the app is allowed to run.

During development, apps contain a provisioning profile that lists the device ids that the app can run on (the developer registers these in the Apple developer portal) and signatures that verify that the developer has a valid certificate signed by Apple.

When the app is published to the App Store, this provisioning profile is stripped out and replaced by Apple with one that they sign which allows the app to run on any device.

The capabilities required by an app (such as access to the camera) are contained in the `info.plist` file and in the app code; the file specified the *reason* that is shown to the user but the code is responsible for requesting access. Simply declaring a usage string in `info.plist` will not prompt the user to grant the permission. This way, permission requests can be made at a time when the context is clear to the user. E.g. when they have tapped a "camera" button in the app.

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying that. So to test locally, I must go online, add my test device's ID in a provisioning profile, download this profile and put it inside my app. When I need to publish my app, this profile is no longer needed or useful because I don't have the device IDs of every apple device out there (but apple does so they create a profile for me)

Comment: Yes, but Xcode can manage all of this for you.  It can create the profile and register new devices when you try to run your app on a new device connected to your Mac. You only need to add a device manually if you are going to send an app to someone remotely for testing (and TestFlight can be a better way to do that).

Comment: And to clarify, it isn't that Apple knows the id of every device, but rather the iOS trust model knows that apps signed by Apple can run on any device, so it doesn't check for the device id in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning Profile is used for security purposes

- [[Development Provisioning Profile]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292735/4770877)
- [[Distribution Provisioning Profile]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60829450/4770877)

[[iOS permission]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73918977/4770877) uses Info.plist + source code