# Do I need to edit provisioning after changing AppID

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have app on appstore. Until this day it was not using push notifications. Right now I would like to add aps to my app. I edited my AppID by generate SSL certificates for my push notification server. Do I also need to regenerate provisioning profile what was associated with this changed AppID?

Comment: Yes it is ;) Sorry If I was not clear here. I had AppID and provisioning profile what are used by appstore app already. Now I edited AppID by generating SSL certificates for push notification servers. The question is do I also need re-generate my old provisioning profile with new edited AppID or maybe Apple is smart enough to figure out that AppID has changed and I dont need to re-generate provisioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

**Regenerate Provisioning Profile when changing App ID**.

As seen in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html), if you change your App ID, you then need to also change your Provisioning Profile.

As exemplified in this diagram below *(for a Team Provisioning Profile)* and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362652/what-is-a-provisioning-profile-used-for-when-developing-iphone-applications), *Provisioning Profile will contain a set of iPhone Development Certificates, Unique Device Identifiers and an **App ID***.

[image]

> You can edit an App ID directly using Member Center. In Member Center, select Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
> Under Identifiers, select App IDs.
> Select the App ID you want to change, and click Edit.
> Select the corresponding checkboxes to enable the app services you want to allow.

**followed by**

> Later, you’ll regenerate the provisioning profiles that use the App ID.